# Showing two different scales on the axis

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have this sample code where I am plotting two variables on two vertical axis. 
One has real range 0-1 and another one has integer range 0-4. I would like to show 
both values simultaneously, but I do not know how.

I looked into [this example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/how-do-i-vertically-stack-two-graphs-with-the-same-x-scale-but-a-different-y-sc) on cross validated that was accepted, but I noticed that when I run the code, both vertical axes have the same scale.

I would need for two scales to be different. Please help.

Comment: You're right. Put `axis(side=2)` before `par(new=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. Do you, btw, know how can I get rid of two labels over top of each other on the left axis?

Comment: Can you provide the code that causes this overlap?

Comment: trial <- c(1:10)
behavior <- c(0.0,0,0.5,0.5,0.7,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0)
prompt <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

plot(trial,behavior,pch=0,type="b",col="red",yaxt="n",ylim=c(0,1))
axis(side=2)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(trial,prompt,pch=1,type="b",col="blue",yaxt="n",ylim=c(0,4))
axis(side=4)

Comment: plot(..., ylab=""); mtext("left label", side=2); mtext("right label", side=4)